# Internet doesn't work by default

Tags: networking, internet-connection, dhcp, dhclient

After upgrading to Precise, I am required to run 'sudo dhclient eth0' in a terminal in order to get the internet to work. Everything worked perfectly fine on Oneiric, so It's really puzzling me.

I'm thinking it could possibly be something with the kernel, but who knows.

---

Output of dmesg:

```
[    0.247891] system 00:01: [io  0x0290-0x030f] has been reserved
[    0.247896] system 00:01: [io  0x0290-0x0297] has been reserved
[    0.247901] system 00:01: [io  0x0880-0x088f] has been reserved
[    0.247908] system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.247931] pnp 00:02: [dma 4]
[    0.247935] pnp 00:02: [io  0x0000-0x000f]
[    0.247939] pnp 00:02: [io  0x0080-0x0090]
[    0.247943] pnp 00:02: [io  0x0094-0x009f]
[    0.247947] pnp 00:02: [io  0x00c0-0x00df]
[    0.248033] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
[    0.248125] pnp 00:03: [io  0x0070-0x0073]
[    0.248187] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.248205] pnp 00:04: [io  0x0061]
[    0.248260] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0800 (active)
[    0.248277] pnp 00:05: [io  0x00f0-0x00ff]
[    0.248292] pnp 00:05: [irq 13]
[    0.248348] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
[    0.248583] pnp 00:06: [io  0x03f0-0x03f5]
[    0.248588] pnp 00:06: [io  0x03f7]
[    0.248597] pnp 00:06: [irq 6]
[    0.248601] pnp 00:06: [dma 2]
[    0.248690] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0700 (active)
[    0.248998] pnp 00:07: [io  0x03f8-0x03ff]
[    0.249008] pnp 00:07: [irq 4]
[    0.249122] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
[    0.249479] pnp 00:08: [io  0x0400-0x04bf]
[    0.249584] system 00:08: [io  0x0400-0x04bf] has been reserved
[    0.249591] system 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.249628] pnp 00:09: [mem 0xffb80000-0xffbfffff]
[    0.249690] pnp 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
[    0.250049] pnp 00:0a: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff]
[    0.250167] system 00:0a: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] has been reserved
[    0.250173] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.250302] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.250307] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x7ff00000-0x7fffffff]
[    0.250311] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed000ff]
[    0.250316] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x0000046e-0x0000056d]
[    0.250320] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x7fee0000-0x7fefffff]
[    0.250324] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.250328] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x00100000-0x7fedffff]
[    0.250332] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
[    0.250336] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xfed14000-0xfed1dfff]
[    0.250341] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed9ffff]
[    0.250345] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
[    0.250349] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xffb00000-0xffb7ffff]
[    0.250353] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0xfff00000-0xffffffff]
[    0.250357] pnp 00:0b: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000effff]
[    0.250409] pnp 00:0b: disabling [mem 0x0000046e-0x0000056d] because it overlaps 0000:01:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0x00000000-0x0007ffff pref]
[    0.250419] pnp 00:0b: disabling [mem 0x0000046e-0x0000056d disabled] because it overlaps 0000:03:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
[    0.250430] pnp 00:0b: disabling [mem 0x0000046e-0x0000056d disabled] because it overlaps 0000:04:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0x00000000-0x0001ffff pref]
[    0.250524] system 00:0b: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff] could not be reserved
[    0.250530] system 00:0b: [mem 0x7ff00000-0x7fffffff] has been reserved
[    0.250536] system 00:0b: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed000ff] has been reserved
[    0.250541] system 00:0b: [mem 0x7fee0000-0x7fefffff] could not be reserved
[    0.250547] system 00:0b: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] could not be reserved
[    0.250552] system 00:0b: [mem 0x00100000-0x7fedffff] could not be reserved
[    0.250558] system 00:0b: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff] could not be reserved
[    0.250563] system 00:0b: [mem 0xfed14000-0xfed1dfff] has been reserved
[    0.250568] system 00:0b: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed9ffff] has been reserved
[    0.250574] system 00:0b: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff] has been reserved
[    0.250579] system 00:0b: [mem 0xffb00000-0xffb7ffff] has been reserved
[    0.250585] system 00:0b: [mem 0xfff00000-0xffffffff] has been reserved
[    0.250590] system 00:0b: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000effff] has been reserved
[    0.250596] system 00:0b: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
[    0.250614] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 12 devices
[    0.250617] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
[    0.250624] PnPBIOS: Disabled by ACPI PNP
[    0.288725] PCI: max bus depth: 1 pci_try_num: 2
[    0.288786] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xfb000000-0xfb07ffff pref]
[    0.288792] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-01]
[    0.288797] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [io  0xa000-0xafff]
[    0.288804] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.288811] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.288820] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-02]
[    0.288825] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [io  0x9000-0x9fff]
[    0.288833] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.288840] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.288851] pci 0000:03:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xfde00000-0xfde0ffff pref]
[    0.288856] pci 0000:00:1c.4: PCI bridge to [bus 03-03]
[    0.288861] pci 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.288869] pci 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0xfd700000-0xfd7fffff]
[    0.288876] pci 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.288887] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdc1ffff pref]
[    0.288891] pci 0000:00:1c.5: PCI bridge to [bus 04-04]
[    0.288897] pci 0000:00:1c.5:   bridge window [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
[    0.288904] pci 0000:00:1c.5:   bridge window [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.288911] pci 0000:00:1c.5:   bridge window [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.288920] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05-05]
[    0.288926] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    0.288933] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff]
[    0.288940] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.288971] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    0.288979] pci 0000:00:01.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.288991] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    0.288998] pci 0000:00:1c.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.289008] pci 0000:00:1c.4: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    0.289014] pci 0000:00:1c.4: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.289030] pci 0000:00:1c.5: PCI INT B -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    0.289037] pci 0000:00:1c.5: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.289047] pci 0000:00:1e.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.289054] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.289058] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.289063] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.289067] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.289072] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x7ff00000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.289077] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 0 [io  0xa000-0xafff]
[    0.289081] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.289086] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 2 [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.289092] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 0 [io  0x9000-0x9fff]
[    0.289096] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.289101] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.289106] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.289110] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xfd700000-0xfd7fffff]
[    0.289115] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.289120] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 0 [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
[    0.289124] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.289129] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.289134] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    0.289138] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff]
[    0.289143] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.289148] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.289152] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.289157] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.289161] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.289166] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 8 [mem 0x7ff00000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.289233] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.289360] IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.289754] TCP established hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    0.290351] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.290670] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 131072 bind 65536)
[    0.290674] TCP reno registered
[    0.290680] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.290703] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.290868] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.290911] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    0.290932] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    0.290956] pci 0000:00:1a.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[    0.290975] pci 0000:00:1a.1: PCI INT B disabled
[    0.290992] pci 0000:00:1a.2: PCI INT D -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    0.291012] pci 0000:00:1a.2: PCI INT D disabled
[    0.291031] pci 0000:00:1a.7: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    0.291068] pci 0000:00:1a.7: PCI INT C disabled
[    0.291104] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    0.291123] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    0.291135] pci 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    0.291155] pci 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B disabled
[    0.291166] pci 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    0.291185] pci 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT C disabled
[    0.291198] pci 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    0.291219] pci 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A disabled
[    0.291258] pci 0000:01:00.0: Boot video device
[    0.291273] PCI: CLS 4 bytes, default 64
[    0.291857] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.291876] type=2000 audit(1336753420.284:1): initialized
[    0.337724] highmem bounce pool size: 64 pages
[    0.337734] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.349241] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.349365] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.350418] fuse init (API version 7.17)
[    0.350611] msgmni has been set to 1685
[    0.351179] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    0.351229] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.351233] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.351247] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.351450] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.351502] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.351585] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.351639] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.351728] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.351779] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.351875] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.351927] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.352094] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.352143] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.352311] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x22220
[    0.352315] intel_idle: does not run on family 6 model 23
[    0.352446] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    0.352455] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.352556] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
[    0.352562] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.352650] ACPI: Fan [FAN] (on)
[    0.355667] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    0.355673] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THRM] (26 C)
[    0.355750] ERST: Table is not found!
[    0.355753] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    0.355898] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.376332] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.376582] isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
[    0.709133] Freeing initrd memory: 13792k freed
[    0.729743] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    0.816786] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.832385] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.835605] brd: module loaded
[    0.837138] loop: module loaded
[    0.837452] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: version 2.13
[    0.837473] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT A -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    0.837480] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: MAP [ P0 P2 P1 P3 ]
[    0.837546] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.838099] scsi0 : ata_piix
[    0.838253] scsi1 : ata_piix
[    0.839183] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xf900 ctl 0xf800 bmdma 0xf500 irq 19
[    0.839192] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xf700 ctl 0xf600 bmdma 0xf508 irq 19
[    0.839239] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: PCI INT A -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    0.839246] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: MAP [ P0 -- P1 -- ]
[    0.839300] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.5: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.839708] scsi2 : ata_piix
[    0.839841] scsi3 : ata_piix
[    0.840301] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xf200 ctl 0xf100 bmdma 0xee00 irq 19
[    0.840308] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xf000 ctl 0xef00 bmdma 0xee08 irq 19
[    0.840429] pata_acpi 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    0.840467] pata_acpi 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.840488] pata_acpi 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    0.841159] Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.841205] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.841210] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    0.841322] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.841515] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.841542] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    0.841567] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.841573] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.841658] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.845582] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: cache line size of 4 is not supported
[    0.845610] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: irq 18, io mem 0xfdfff000
[    0.860022] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.860264] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.860272] hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    0.860404] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    0.860424] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.860430] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.860512] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.864413] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: cache line size of 4 is not supported
[    0.864438] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: irq 23, io mem 0xfdffe000
[    0.880021] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.880227] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.880234] hub 2-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    0.880369] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.880396] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.880431] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    0.880443] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.880449] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.880529] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.880574] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io base 0x0000ff00
[    0.880803] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.880811] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.880929] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[    0.880940] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.880946] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.881039] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    0.881081] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: irq 21, io base 0x0000fe00
[    0.881302] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.881310] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.881427] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: PCI INT D -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    0.881438] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.881443] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.881523] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    0.881551] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: irq 19, io base 0x0000fd00
[    0.881774] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.881781] hub 5-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.881899] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    0.881910] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.881915] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.881993] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    0.882021] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io base 0x0000fc00
[    0.882244] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.882252] hub 6-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.882370] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    0.882381] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.882386] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.882467] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    0.882495] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: irq 19, io base 0x0000fb00
[    0.882735] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.882742] hub 7-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.882858] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    0.882869] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.882875] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.882954] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[    0.882982] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: irq 18, io base 0x0000fa00
[    0.883205] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.883213] hub 8-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.883435] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    0.883535] i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
[    0.883926] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.883936] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.884187] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.884433] rtc_cmos 00:03: RTC can wake from S4
[    0.884582] rtc_cmos 00:03: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    0.884612] rtc0: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    0.884719] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.884854] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.884917] EISA: Probing bus 0 at eisa.0
[    0.884921] EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    0.884925] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    0.884929] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    0.884932] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    0.884936] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    0.884940] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    0.884943] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    0.884947] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    0.884950] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    0.884954] EISA: Detected 0 cards.
[    0.884969] cpufreq-nforce2: No nForce2 chipset.
[    0.884973] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.884976] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.884980] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    0.885476] TCP cubic registered
[    0.885708] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.886771] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.886799] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    0.886837] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
[    0.887028] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    0.887047] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.902579]   Magic number: 12:339:388
[    0.902592] usb usb6: hash matches
[    0.902687] rtc_cmos 00:03: setting system clock to 2012-05-11 16:23:41 UTC (1336753421)
[    0.903185] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.903189] EDD information not available.
[    1.170710] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.181439] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.288020] Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2499.999 MHz.
[    1.288028] Switching to clocksource tsc
[    1.292016] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[    1.486745] ata2.00: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.486762] ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.640115] ata1.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    1.640130] ata1.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.648342] ata1.00: ATA-7: Maxtor 7Y250M0, YAR511W0, max UDMA/133
[    1.648348] ata1.00: 490234752 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 
[    1.664325] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.664531] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Maxtor 7Y250M0   YAR5 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.664745] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 490234752 512-byte logical blocks: (251 GB/233 GiB)
[    1.664809] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.664838] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.664843] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.664884] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.691699]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
[    1.692348] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.692461] Freeing unused kernel memory: 740k freed
[    1.692820] Write protecting the kernel text: 5828k
[    1.692851] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2376k
[    1.692854] NX-protecting the kernel data: 4412k
[    1.723980] udevd[92]: starting version 175
[    1.865339] Floppy drive(s): fd0 is 1.44M
[    1.865429] pata_jmicron 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    1.865478] pata_jmicron 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.867875] sky2: driver version 1.30
[    1.867926] sky2 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    1.867942] sky2 0000:04:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.867979] sky2 0000:04:00.0: Yukon-2 EC chip revision 2
[    1.868111] sky2 0000:04:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.868174] scsi4 : pata_jmicron
[    1.869802] sky2 0000:04:00.0: eth0: addr 00:01:29:a4:16:0a
[    1.869828] scsi5 : pata_jmicron
[    1.869943] ata5: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0xdf00 ctl 0xde00 bmdma 0xdb00 irq 16
[    1.869949] ata6: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0xdd00 ctl 0xdc00 bmdma 0xdb08 irq 16
[    1.880053] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    1.884052] FDC 0 is a post-1991 82077
[    2.032611] ata5.00: ATAPI: _NEC DVD+/-RW ND-3450A, 103C, max UDMA/33
[    2.048585] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[    2.049777] scsi 4:0:0:0: CD-ROM            _NEC     DVD+-RW ND-3450A 103C PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.051048] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.051054] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.051283] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.051483] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.079838] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.079844] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.236660] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   12.150230] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   12.177342] udevd[333]: starting version 175
[   12.195524] Adding 417684k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:417684k 
[   12.278032] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   12.516456] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-1/input2
[   12.520297] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1024 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input2
[   12.520753] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1024] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-1:1
[   12.523286] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2011 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input3
[   12.524439] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2011] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-1:2
[   12.545746] type=1400 audit(1336771433.137:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=502 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.546574] type=1400 audit(1336771433.137:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=502 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.547034] type=1400 audit(1336771433.137:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=502 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.626869] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   12.649104] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:081a)
[   12.668665] input: UVC Camera (046d:081a) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input4
[   12.668909] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   12.668914] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   12.697645] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[   12.697721] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   12.697760] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   12.706772] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   12.706778] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   12.735428] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   13.350252] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   13.350267] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   13.350275] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   13.351464] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:28:09 PDT 2012
[   13.356785] hda_codec: ALC889A: BIOS auto-probing.
[   13.357267] init: failsafe main process (658) killed by TERM signal
[   13.372756] input: HDA Intel Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input5
[   13.373173] input: HDA Intel Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input6
[   13.373568] input: HDA Intel Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[   13.373954] input: HDA Intel Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   13.374339] input: HDA Intel Line-Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   13.374715] input: HDA Intel Line-Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   13.375109] input: HDA Intel Line-Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   13.375724] input: HDA Intel Line-Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   13.475252] type=1400 audit(1336771434.065:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=735 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.477026] type=1400 audit(1336771434.069:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=735 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.477695] type=1400 audit(1336771434.069:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=735 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.479048] type=1400 audit(1336771434.069:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=734 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.488994] type=1400 audit(1336771434.081:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=738 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.489972] type=1400 audit(1336771434.081:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=738 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH, well I solved the problem. :D All I did was add a script to init like told in [this](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/) link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether it's set to use DHCP?

> Network Indicator > Edit Connections > Choose your network connection > Edit > IPv4 Settings > Method > Automatic (DHCP) > **Save**

[image: Network settings]

Comment: I just checked it and it is using dhcp.

Comment: Love the pic @RobinJ but its hard to see whats happening there ;)

Comment: @ruffEdgz I know, it's a bit wide on dual screen :p
@AdamMartinez Output of `dmesg`, please.

Comment: K. It's been posted

Comment: The animated gif thing is amazing, right click and "Open Image" to see it larger. what program did you use to capture?

Comment: @mateo_salta Byzanz

Comment: @AdamMartinez Go back to the network settings dialog, and this time, go to the *IPv6* tab. Set the *Method* to *Ignored*. Reboot.

Comment: @RobinJ No luck. :/

Comment: No (logical) idea then... This is why upgrading is never recommended.

Comment: Darn it, alright. Thanks for trying, I guess. :)